# More efficient way of writing multiple React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a page where I render 8 components, the only thing different is an the values iterates...

```
<Item
  classModifier="step"
  image={Step1}
  heading={Copy.one.heading}
 />
 <Item
  classModifier="step"
  image={Step2}
  heading={Copy.two.heading}
 />
 <Item
  classModifier="step"
  image={Step3}
  heading={Copy.three.heading}
 />
```

The above works, but is there a more efficient way of writing this? I'm aware this probably doesn't adhere to DRY methodology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an array containing your numbers in `string` format
2. Create another array that will hold your `Step1, Step2, ...` **variables**
3. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) those items into `<Item>` Components based on the `current string` and its `index` in the previously described array

---

You'll have something that looks like this

```
const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const steps = [Step1, Step2, Step3];     // These need to be defined before

return (
  <div>
    {numbers.map((s, i) => (
      <Item key={i} classModifier='step' image={steps[i]} heading={Copy[s].heading}>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

## Edit

- This **requires** that your two arrays are sorted in the same order. Otherwise it will fail to match the steps with their correspondant number
- To avoid that you should put objects instead of raw strings in your array. **[Check out Gabriele's answer for a more robust & maintainable implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783875/more-efficient-way-of-writing-multiple-react-components/54784070#54784070)**

Comment: You should probably combine the two arrays to one. Havingtwo arrays that are **required** to match their order is not a good pattern.

Comment: Yes that's the __right way to do it__ even if this works. I included a link to your answer instead of editing mine because then it will be exactly like yours (which you thought of first)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array and map over it returning the Components

```js
render(){
    const Items = [
      {step:Step1, heading: Copy.one.heading},
      {step:Step2, heading: Copy.two.heading},
      {step:Step3, heading: Copy.three.heading}
    ]

   
    return Items.map(({step, heading},index)=><Item 
      key={index}
      classModifier="step"
      image={step}
      heading={heading}
    />)
}
```

---

The index used for the `key` prop is usually an anti-pattern although in this case where the array is manually build it should not pose any issues.
Also, I do not know more about where `Step1` and `Copy` are coming and their format, so i just manually built the array. Perhaps the format you have allows you to directly map over some list and have access to that info.

Answer (score 0):

Without know exactly how the data is structured or if you can edit the structure, a common pattern is to use map().

```
render(){
   const data = [
      {
         image: "a.jpg",
         heading: "A",
         key: 0
      }, 
      {
         image: "b.jpg",
         heading: "B",
         key: 1
      }
   ];
   const someComponents = data.map(d => (
      <Item key={d.key} classModifier="step" image={d.image} />
   ));
   return (
      <div>{someComponents}</div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

separate data and view. and render view by iterating data.

```
data = [
    { image: Step1, heading: Copy.one.heading },
    { image: Step2, heading: Copy.two.heading },
    { image: Step3, heading: Copy.three.heading },
]
data.map((obj, index) => {
    return <Item
        key={index}
        classModifier="step"
        image={obj.index}
        heading={obj.heading}
    />
})
```